# R Merge Tabulations of data from different files

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am using R to analyize multiple experiments in which the results are stored in multiple CSV files.  I run `table()` to tabulate the data and get results like the following

```
Tabulations of Combination1.csv
A  1000
B  50
C  200            
Tabulations of Combination2.csv
A 25
B 1500
D 30
Tabulations of Combination3.csv
B 19
C 500
E 2000
```

I want to build a table that combines these tabulations.

```
Combination A     B     C     D    E
c1          1000   50    200   N/A  N/A
c2          25    1500   N/A   30   N/A
c3          N/A    19    500   N/A  2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it using `tidyr` and  `dplyr`:

**Data**

```
c1 <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(1000, 50, 200))
c2 <- rep(LETTERS[c(1:2, 4)], c(25, 1500, 30))
c3 <- rep(LETTERS[c(2:3, 5)], c(19, 500, 2000))
```

**Code**

```
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
allC <- list(c1 = c1, c2 = c2, c3 = c3)
# get all tables in data.frame format
ldply(names(allC), function(x) {
   tab <- table(allC[[x]]) 
   data.frame(Combination = x, element = names(tab), Freq = c(tab))
}) %>% spread(element, Freq)

#   Combination    A    B   C  D    E
# 1          c1 1000   50 200 NA   NA
# 2          c2   25 1500  NA 30   NA
# 3          c3   NA   19 500 NA 2000
```

**Explanation**

You transform all your tables to a `data.frame` first, where you append the name of the respective element. Then you use `spread` to spread out the values.

Comment: I'm using parLapply(clus, comboName, function(x){ table(read.csv(x)$code)}) to build the `allC` list.  How can I add the comboName to the returned lists?

Comment: In my example `allC` contains all the _raw data_ (*not* the table itself). So I guess (assuming that `comboName` holds the names of the `* .csv`) you need to do something like `allC <- setNames(parLapply(clus, comboName, function(x) read.csv(x)$code), comboName)`. This reads column `code` of each `csv` into a list and assigns the name `comboName` to it. Then you should be able to directly proceed with `ldply` as in my example.

Comment: Thank you Thothal.  I tried using setNames inside the parLapply function which clearly didn't work.  I'm surprised that works with parallel order of operations but I'm happy that it does.

Comment: Well, `parLapply` returns a `list` in the same way as `lapply` (only difference is that the former uses parallel computation). Once the final list is returned, `setNames` assigns the name. If you use it inside your `parLapply` function it assigns a name to the _table_ which is not what you want.

Comment: My concern was the order in which lapply or parLapply would return the items in the list matching the order in list of comboNames.  In my small scale test of 100 it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- table(c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 50), rep("C", 200)))
y <- table(c(rep("A", 25), rep("B", 1500), rep("D", 30)))
z <- table(c(rep("B", 19), rep("C", 500), rep("E", 2000)))

X <- data.frame(x) %>% spread(Var1, Freq)
Y <- data.frame(y) %>% spread(Var1, Freq)
Z <- data.frame(z) %>% spread(Var1, Freq)

X %>% full_join(Y) %>% full_join(Z) %>%
  mutate(Combination = paste0("c", seq(1,3)))
```

Result:

```
> X %>% full_join(Y) %>% full_join(Z) %>%
+ mutate(Combination = paste0("c", seq(1,3)))
Joining, by = c("A", "B")
Joining, by = c("B", "C")
     A    B   C  D    E Combination
1 1000   50 200 NA   NA          c1
2   25 1500  NA 30   NA          c2
3   NA   19 500 NA 2000          c3
```

Please think for the next time to provide `x`, `y` and `z` objects for a reproducible example :)